# C# Concepts: what the "LIST" keyword represents?

Tags: c#, list

I have been doing a crash course of C# OOP and am curious to know what the "LIST" keyword represents in the code below:

```
var actors = new List<Actor>();
```

Comment: My `C#` may be a little rusty, but I don't think that is `C#` syntax...Keep in mind that `C#` is strongly-typed, so `var foo =` isn't allowed (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @jonathan: it works, since c# 3.0.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic2

Comment: @Jonathan: it's new to C# 3.0, I believe. The compiler infers the type of the variable based on the type of the initializing value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: It really must be a crash course, to have you missed collections in C#.

Comment: @Zeno and @Outis: Thanks. I've not touched C# since 2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` is a class with a type parameter.  This is called "generics" and allows you to manipulate objects opaquely within the class, especially useful for container classes like  a list or a queue.

A container just stores things, it doesn't really need to know what it is storing.  We could implement it like this without generics:

```
class List
{
    public List( ) { }
    public void Add( object toAdd ) { /*add 'toAdd' to an object array*/ }
    public void Remove( object toRemove ) { /*remove 'toRemove' from array*/ }
    public object operator []( int index ) { /*index into storage array and return value*/ }
}
```

However, we don't have type safety.  I could abuse the hell out of that collection like this:

```
List list = new List( );
list.Add( 1 );
list.Add( "uh oh" );
list.Add( 2 );
int i = (int)list[1]; // boom goes the dynamite
```

Using generics in C# allows us to use these types of container classes in a type safe manner.

```
class List<T>
{
    // 'T' is our type.  We don't need to know what 'T' is,
    // we just need to know that it is a type.

    public void Add( T toAdd ) { /*same as above*/ }
    public void Remove( T toAdd ) { /*same as above*/ }
    public T operator []( int index ) { /*same as above*/ } 
}
```

Now if we try to add something that does not belong we get a *compile* time error, much preferable to an error that occurs when our program is executing.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>( );
list.Add( 1 );               // fine
list.Add( "not this time" ); // doesn't compile, you know there is a problem
```

Hope that helped.  Sorry if I made any syntax errors in there, my C# is rusty ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's not a keyword, it's a class identifier.

Answer (score 2):

List<Actor>() is describing a list of Actor objects.  Typically a list is a collection of objects that are ordered in some way and can be accessed by an index.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a generic OO concept. It is a type in the .NET library. I would suggest to pick up a good [C# & .NET book](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=books%20%5bc%23%5d%20%5b.net%5d).